# onblur function call in handlebar template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am having problem passing value to a function called inside onblur event of handlebar template.

```
<div class="property" id="property">
  <span class="innertitle">Property/Site Details</span></br>
  <table id="propDetails" width="400" border="0">{{#dispycolumns}}
     <tr>
        <td>{{FieldLabel}}</td>
        <td>
          <input name="{{fieldName}}" type="text" value="{{FieldValue}}" maxlength="100" onblur="validateFields(this.value,this.name,{{FieldLabel}});" />
        </td>
     </tr>{{/dispycolumns}}
  </table></br></br>
</div></br></br>
<input style="font-size:12px;float:right;margin-top: -19px;margin-left: 59px;background-color:#0099FF;" type="button" name="Next" value="Next" onclick="savePropertyDetails();loadConsumptionData()" />
```

In above code i am calling validateFields() function with 3 arguments.I have a problem passing the third argument {{FieldLabel}}. I need single quotes around it to properly compile.
Request help in doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap quotation marks around {{FieldLabel}} where it is intended to be a string literal argument:

```
onblur="validateFields(this.value, this.name, '{{FieldLabel}}');"
```

Comment: Sorry to say that it is not working. I get syntax error.If i use just {{FieldLabel}} also function is not called due to syntax error.This is because whole of the above html is rendered using handlebars,so i have declared a variable  like var teplate_src="<div class="property" id="property">"; This is why i think quotes mismatch is happening.

Comment: If you are creating your template source as a string then you will certainly need to escape the quotes within it using a backslash, [\]: var template_src="<div class=\"property\" id=\"property\">";

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had tried escapinng before but it had not worked..Dont know what had gone wrong.